# Issue with bootstrap and positioning (input-group)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

The code is below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zapremina_motora, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zapremina_motora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            <span class="input-group-addon">cc</span>
        </div>

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zapremina_motora, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I have is that the browser gives me textbox and span addon with "cc" text separated. Photo with the issue added.

Could anyone help with this? I've spent a lot of time trying to fix this but couldn't find the solution.

Picture of the issue:

[image: Picture of the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the lines with this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zapremina_motora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", aria-describedby="addon1" } })
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="addon1">cc</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but it still doesn't work. Still there is a big space between the textbox and addon text.

Comment: Try with the edited one. And possesses please check if your using any custom templates that overrides bootstrap

Comment: Success. Thank you once more. The default ASP.NET MVC line in the layout file: @Styles.Render("~/Content/css"), was the problem. As soon as I replaced it with <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> it started working.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. Thanks again.

Comment: For some other people with the similar problem: You can leave @Styles.Render("~/Content/css"), but you need to go to Site.css file and remove : input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}